# MySQLdb executemany using a list as input?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am wanting to use an executemany within my program to store 20 records at once, heres what it says in the documentation...

```
c.executemany(
  """INSERT INTO breakfast (name, spam, eggs, sausage, price)
  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
  [
  ("Spam and Sausage Lover's Plate", 5, 1, 8, 7.95 ),
  ("Not So Much Spam Plate", 3, 2, 0, 3.95 ),
  ("Don't Wany ANY SPAM! Plate", 0, 4, 3, 5.95 )
  ] )
```

However, I have my values in a list, and would rather not do 18 versions of the above, using an index on my list.

Here is my code below...

```
db = connect_to_db()
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO gkey (keyword, date, time, position) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
params = [(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])]
cursor.executemany(sql, params)
db.commit()
```

This works fine, and it will commit the first keyword in the list, along with the date, time and position, I do not want to have to repeat the params 19 times like below...

```
db = connect_to_db()
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO gkey (keyword, date, time, position) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
params = [
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])    
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])
(str(keywords[0]), date, time, position[0])

]
cursor.executemany(sql, params)
db.commit()
```

Above an example of what I am trying to avoid (the index needs to be incremented for it to work I know! ;))

I get an error when I try pass the whole list as a value, and I need to pass them one at a time, any ideas? Can execute many do this, or should I be making a loop and updating them one at a time? But I'm pretty sure I tried that and I got a similar error? I didn't note it down though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
params = [(str(keywords[i]), date, time, position[i]) for i in range(20)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So you can loop when defining a variable? I assume this will have other applications when passing params to functions etc?

Comment: It's a list comprehension http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/mapping_lists.html